# What system app handles the screenshots in Lollipop?

Tags: applications, sony-xperia, screenshots

When I take a screenshot using Power button + Volume Down, does anyone know which system app deals with taking that screenshot? I need it for a setup I'm doing on my phone (Xperia) but I can't figure it out which it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SystemUI handles the global screenshot.

SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/screenshot/GlobalScreenshot.java

SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/screenshot/TakeScreenshotService.java